SQL Server 2022 express download error
I was trying to download SQL Server 2022 Express in windows 11 and received an Exit code(Decimal): -2061893606.
Then I checked log and saw SystemConfigurationCheck report.
Everything is okay except this warning. As far I know my defender already closed but still cannot download properly. I saw solutions like run as admin but did not work.



That error is not related to downloading the media. This error really means that SQL Server did not start when Setup wanted to run configuration tasks. To understand why it did not start, check the SQL Server errorlog which should be in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG.
If you see a message about 256 misaligned reads, you are running into a known issue for which Microsoft has published this troubleshooter.
